# How Js through the NPM covert to use for Xampp Server

Tags: javascript, npm

I lake a Js project make through Npm (Pakage.json). I want to run the project in Xampp server

How can I change the project for Xampp Server

Eg : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kzebuu?file=index.js

I lake a Js project make through Npm (Pakage.json). I want to run the project in Xampp server

How can I change the project for Xampp Server

Eg : https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-kzebuu?file=index.js

Comment: Simply install node, and you will be able to build the files, that will be served by xampp in the end

Comment: If you want to run your project with xampp server, you need to shift your project to the htdocs directory in the xampp folder. Then you can simply write localhost:<port>/<filename>.html as url and run your project.